# Convert a static javascript function to dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In a c# MVC project, I was given a view by a front-end designer that contains this little script:

```
 <script>
    $('#PhaseDD').change(function () {
        var chosenValue = $(this).val();
        $('.ProcessDD').hide();
        if (chosenValue == "")
            $('#DefaultProcess').show();
        if (chosenValue == "Planning")
            $('#PlanningProcess').show();
        if (chosenValue == "Procurement")
            $('#ProcurementProcess').show();
        if (chosenValue == "Installation")
            $('#InstallationProcess').show();
        if (chosenValue == "Closure")
            $('#ClosureProcess').show();
    });
</script>
```

I would like to replace all the hard-coded options with a list that comes from the model.  Something like this...

```
<script>
    $('#PhaseDD').change(function () {
        var chosenValue = $(this).val();
        $('.ProcessDD').hide();
        if (chosenValue == "")
            $('#DefaultProcess').show();

        // loop over a list from the model here

        if (chosenValue == " loop-item-name ")
            $('# loop-item-name + Process').show();

       //  end loop

    });
</script>
```

Is this possible? If so, how? And am I even going about this the right way?  I was thinking I could use razor syntax, but that isn't working.

Comment: What about this: `$('#' + chosenValue + 'Process').show()`? You won't need a list for this.

Comment: `$("#" + (chosenValue || "Default") + "Process").show();`

Comment: why are you using if else then? add Process directly to the variable

Answer (score 1):

You can not compare a C# variable to a JS variable. But you can use razor to create a JS variable from a C# variable.

Here is how to fill a JS array with the values of a C# array:

```
@{ 
   // fetch this from ViewModel if it needs to be dynamic
   var cSharpNames = new [] { "Planning", "Procurement"}; 
 }

<script>
    var jsNames = []; // this is a JS array

    @foreach(var name in cSharpNames) {
         <text>jsNames.push(@name);</text>
    }

</script>
```

Then use the `indexOf()` method to search in the jsNames array as has been shown by Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make an array, check to see if the value exists within it, and if it does show it. Something like this:

```
<script>
    $('#PhaseDD').change(function () {
        var chosenValue = $(this).val();
        var processes = ['Planning', 'Procurement'];
        $('.ProcessDD').hide();
        if (chosenValue == "")
            $('#DefaultProcess').show();

        if (processes.indexOf(chosenValue) > -1)
            $('#' + chosenValue + 'Process').show();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok ok... I see what you are thinking, and this is a much better way.  The syntax you have isn't working, but it might be enough to get me there.

Comment: But also, I can't have Planning, Procurment, etc, hard coded.  needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this.

```
    $('#PhaseDD').change(function () {
        var chosenValue = $(this).val();
        $('.ProcessDD').hide();
        if (chosenValue == "")
        {
            $('#DefaultProcess').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#' + chosenValue + 'Process').show();
        }
    });
```